# How do I go to a webpage, load, then do some code?

Tags: c#

I've tried using `Sleep` but that just froze the program. Is it messing up because it's in the timer? I can get it to go to the site and not do code, but once I put other code it doesn't load properly.

I also tried putting code in:
`private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)` but then I had even more problems.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //code here

        if (click == null)
        {   
            webBrowser1.Url = new System.Uri("http://url.com", System.UriKind.Absolute);
            timer1.Stop();
            //load or wait x seconds
            timer1.Start();
        }
```

EDIT:
I'm trying to go from one page to the next and doing code once the page is loaded. If I put code in `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` it messes up the code before it. How do I add `DocumentCompleted` to only this one instance?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I suggest a headline change. The `if` statement in the code is more or less irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Perhaps you just should execute slow operations in a background thread.

Comment: don't use Sleep... Ever! its a blocking call and unless your application is threaded it will will hang; look in the API for a callback ( webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted looks like its along the right lines)

Comment: The [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event will fire when the url has finished loading into the web browser object.

Comment: I'm trying to go from one page to the next and doing code once the page is loaded. If I put code in `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` it messes up the code before it. How do I add `DocumentCompleted` to only this one instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it seems like ur approach is wrong,

1. Open the url in the web browser control.
2. Wait for DocumentCompletedEvent. It will come once page is loaded fully.
3. Write ur code in document completed event based on your criteria/condition.